# Create Table without data aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I just started to use the ksqlDB Confluent feature, and it stood out that it is not possible to proceed with the following command: CREATE TABLE AS SELECT A, B, C FROM [STREAM_A] [EMIT CHANGES];

I wonder why this is not possible or if there's a way of doing it?
Data aggregation here is feeling a heavy process to a simple solution.

Edit 1: Source is a STREAM and not a TABLE.
The field types are:

- String
- Integers
- Record

Let me share an example of the executed command that returns an error as a result.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
WITH (KEY_FORMAT='JSON',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO')
AS
SELECT id
    , timestamp
    , servicename
    , content->assignedcontent
FROM created_stream
WHERE content->assignedcontent IS NOT NULL
[EMIT CHANGES];
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the data/schema you're trying to work with? From the top of my head I thought it was possible to create a table with the results from another table.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt - Edited. My intention was to mention about create a table from another STREAM and not another TABLE.

Comment: Please explain more. By definition, a table is an aggregation of state. If you want a not-null filter, that would be another stream, not a table... Also, `[EMIT CHANGES]` is not valid syntax (the square brackets aren't used)

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer.
Yea, the EMIT CHANGES are there in brackets as optional, I'm not considering them relevant for this question.

So as you are saying, I can't create a table at all with a smaller dataset and fewer fields than the original topic without an aggregation function? 
Briefly explanation of what I pretend to do.
Source Topic [fields A, B, C, D, E] > ksql new STREAM > ksql new table with fields A, B, C only [let's ignore the NULL filter as well > New topic with less fields

Comment: The filtered `A B C` data would just be a filtered stream, not a table. A table requires aggregation, even if that is a simple "group-by key"

Comment: Got it, thank you both!
I'll create a dummy field sourced by an agg function grouped by all the fields to create a table sourced by a stream and keep the same granularity.

Answer (score 1):

> create a table with a smaller dataset and fewer fields than the original topic

I think the confusion here is that you talk about a `TABLE`, but you're actually creating a `STREAM`. The two are different types of object.

- A `STREAM` is an unbounded series of events - just like a Kafka topic. The only difference is that a `STREAM` has a declared schema.
- A `TABLE` is state, for a given key. It's the same as KTable in Kafka Streams if you're familiar with that.

Both are backed by Kafka topics.

So you can do this - note that it's creating a *`STREAM`* not a *`TABLE`*

```sql
CREATE STREAM test_stream
WITH (KEY_FORMAT='JSON',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO')
AS
SELECT id
    , timestamp
    , servicename
    , content->assignedcontent
FROM created_stream
WHERE content->assignedcontent IS NOT NULL;
```

If you really want to create a `TABLE` then use the `LATEST_BY_OFFSET` aggregation, assuming you'd using `id` as your key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table
WITH (KEY_FORMAT='JSON',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO')
AS
SELECT id
    , LATEST_BY_OFFSET(timestamp)
    , LATEST_BY_OFFSET(servicename)
    , LATEST_BY_OFFSET(content->assignedcontent)
FROM created_stream
WHERE content->assignedcontent IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Robin.
At the moment, I'm just exploring the feature, so I'm trying to do something similar as explained here -> [link](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/ksqldb/streams-and-tables/)
Can I do exactly the same code you shared here, but instead of CREATE STREAM it would be CREATE TABLE? I'm trying to assess if this ksqlDB has something as simple as that to mark down whether it is possible or not to do that.

Comment: @boud23 [`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS)`](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-table-as-select/#examples) statements are possible, yes.

Comment: Yea, but just in the cases that the data source is another table and not a stream.

Comment: @boud23 I've edited my answer. I'm not clear why you want to build a table if you don't have any aggregations though. By definition, that is a stream. It's not a table :) Feel free to head over to https://forum.confluent.io/ to discuss in more depth there - StackOverflow isn't so well suited to back & forth.

Comment: Thank you @RobinMoffatt.
Discussion ticket is now open in the Confluent forum - (https://forum.confluent.io/t/create-table-without-data-aggregation/4493)